# $.ajaxの終了後にalert()を呼び出さないとデータの登録がされない

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQueryを利用してAjaxでデータ登録をしたいときに、alert()を呼び出す場合は、問題なくデータを登録することができますが、alert()を呼び出さない場合はデータの登録に失敗します。

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://xxx',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(form_data),
})
.done(function(data){
    console.log("登録完了")
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    console.log("登録失敗")
});
alert("END") // ここをコメントアウトするとデータは登録できない
```

この`alert()`の部分が`console.log()`でも`setTimeout()`でもだめで、`alert()`でなければ動きません。なぜ`alert()`のみがうまく動くのかわかりません。

ちなみに、`.done()`と`.fail()`はデータが登録できたorできなかったにかかわらず、呼び出されません。ここも不思議でなりません。

`$.ajax()`の中に以下のようにしてもログは出ませんでした。

```
$.ajax()({
    success: function(result){
        console.log('my message' + result);
    }
})
```

話が脱線しましたが、なぜ`alert()`を呼び出す場合は登録が成功するかがわかりません。

回答をお待ちしております。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XHR (`$.ajax()`)は非同期処理ですので、実行したあとにある程度時間があかないと送ったデータがサーバまで届きません。おそらく、イベントループに入るまでブラウザは何もしないのではないかと思います。

■ `alert()` も `e.preventDefault()`もない場合 → XHRのリクエストが処理されれる前にフォームが送信され、XHRを要求したHTML文書自体がXHRの要求ごと消える。

■ `alert()` を入れた場合 → ダイアログを表示してイベントループに入り、XHRの要求が実行される。

■ `e.preventDefault()`がある場合 → フォーム送信されないので、HTML文書が生き残り、XHRの要求も処理される。

Answer (score 0):

すみません、自己解決しましたので回答します。
`e.preventDefault();`を置くことで対応できました。

```
$.ajax({
    ...
})
.done(function(data){
    console.log("登録完了")
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    console.log("登録失敗")
});
e.preventDefault();
```

`e.preventDefault();`と`alert()`の違いについて考察をしようと思います。

Comment: どうやらイベントハンドラ内のコードの一部だったようですね。質問のコードだけでは意味不明すぎて回答のしようもない話なのですが、ぜひ前後を含む(できるだけ全体の)コードを掲載するようにしてください！（この場合はイベントを起こすもとのHTMLも必要そうですが）

Comment: @hinaloe さん
意味不明ですよね、大変申し訳ございません。おっしゃる通り、`x.onsubmit = function(e){...}`のようにsubmitの際のイベントを取り扱う部分でした。お騒がせいたしましたorz